# I read online that one should wait at least 1.5 months before submitting a revised article. Is this advisable?

Tags: peer-review

Otherwise the editor and the reviewers will think that one's work was rushed. Do you concur?

Comment: This is likely to depend on the field...

Comment: Don't believe everything you read online. Do a good job revising, and send it back.

Comment: I don't concur.   You can spend 1 year to address reviewer comments, and the paper could still be poor.   At the end of the day, it's about how well you've addressed the comments.  This could be one day or x years.

Comment: That sounds like astoundingly bad advice. There seems to be no limit to the foolishness of some of the misconceptions one can encounter online. In general, I suggest ignoring any advice that smacks of “gaming the system”. Such techniques have no place in academia, and are followed only by mediocre researchers who are insecure about the quality of the work they produce. Perhaps worst of all, these academic “life hacks” almost never work. This one certainly won’t.

Comment: I am not saying the Q is particularly smart but it does not necessarily deserve down votes.  Down votes should be for the online source of such a bizarre statement, not for OP that apparently doesn't trust that much.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't think that you could downvote questions...

Answer (score 2):

I suspect this may depend on the field.

It also depends strongly on the nature of the comments that you received. If the comments are something that are easy to address (adding some refs, clarifying some points in text, etc.), then there is something to be said for resubmitting as soon as possible (while seriously addressing the points made by the referees). Your referees will typically be thankful for this, since the article (and their own thoughts on it) will be still fresh in their mind. This means that it will be a lot less work for them to reassess the article. (I often aim to resubmit in a day or two in these cases.)

On the other hand, if the referees have more profound comments that may require you to produce new results to address (new experiments or new calculations). Then, of course, you should take as much time as is necessary to adequately address the comments.

The most important thing in any case is to take the referees seriously. Even if you think that the comments of a referee are misguides, that usually means that you have not explained your point clearly enough.

Answer (score 1):

Submit it when it's ready: that would be the actual interval of time to complete the work, along with all the competing responsibilities you or your coauthors may have.

What *I've* read is typically to submit a revised article in *less than a month*: although, where I read this was in emails from journal editors. Of course, those editors are flexible when the work will take longer to complete (for example, if new experiments are necessary) and different journals have different expectations.

Comment: I've got a deadline of three months.

Comment: @Philosopherofscience Then I'd suggest completing it in less than 3 months if possible, asking permission if you need longer than 3 months, and not worrying about the timing besides that. Certainly not delaying submission simply to make it look like you are working hard (though it can be a helpful editing strategy to re-read your own writing after letting some time pass - that's not delaying for the sake of appearances, though).